# can colons be used with an extract statement?

Tags: php

I have been working on updating and cleaning up some of my code from last year, below is an excerpt of an if statement, I was wondering if it was possible to use colons instead of curly braces, but with an extract statement in the middle I'm not sure how to proceed, if it's not possible I'll accept it, thanks.

```
<?php if ($num>0) { ?>
html
<?php
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
extract($row);
?>
html
<?php if ($id != 1) { ?>
html
<?php } ?>
html
<?php } ?>
html
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Colons do not work in this instance, but this code really needs some formatting cleanup

Comment: I would also recommend against using `extract()` and stick with accessing the data from the `$row` array.

Comment: You can always use colon instead of braces, it doesn't matter what's inside it.

Comment: @NigelRen but removing the extract($row); causes the data to not be displayed, all the data becomes "Undefined variable"

Comment: You should use explicit assignments like `$id = $row['id'];`, not `extract()`.

Comment: @Barmar ah! thank you very much, that works, really appreciate it.